# How to get the virtual path to where WCF is hosted on IIS rather than the physical path?

Tags: vb.net, wcf, iis, hosting, virtual-directory

I have a WCF Service hosted on IIS server, however i try to get the path to which the service is hosted on the IIS, that is similar to: 192.168.1.xx/WCFHosted/VirtualDirectory, by using the below code:

```
System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.ApplicationPhysicalPath
```

The above returns a path to the Physical path corresponding to where the IIS Hosted WCF is originally linked from, that is Ex: D/MyService/WCFHosted,

How can i return the IIS Hosted path for the WCF,

Please Advise,
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below code snippets.

```
System.Environment.MachineName+"/" + System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.SiteName +System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.ApplicationVirtualPath;
```

We can convert the Machine name to an IP address by using `DNS.GetHostAddress(hostname)` method.

```
var result = Dns.GetHostAddresses(Environment.MachineName).ToList();
            foreach (var item in result)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item);
            }
```

Feel free to let me know if there is anything I can help with.

Comment: Dear @Abraham, Many thanks for your reply, as it solved my problem, but i have a question, in order return only the IPv4 values am using the below code: Dns.GetHostAddresses(Environment.MachineName).Where(Function(w) w.AddressFamily = System.Net.Sockets.AddressFamily.InterNetwork), however, this returns the IPv4 for (Ethernet adapter Ethernet 3 / Ethernet adapter VMware Network Adapter VMnet1 / Ethernet adapter VMware Network Adapter VMnet8 / Wireless LAN adapter Wi-Fi) and i only need the last one, is there a way to get only that IP or will it always be the last one in returned list??

Comment: We have to filter the list since there might be multiple network interfaces locally.
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/8bc56dba-007b-488f-b4ec-5b674476917e/i-need-just-ipv4?forum=csharpgeneral
Besides, here is a way to obtain IPV4.
Dns.GetHostEntry(Environment.MachineName).AddressList.First(a => a.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork);